# Xamarin testcloud, ipa binary link calabash

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, calabash-ios, xamarin-test-cloud

How I can link my ipa binary with calabash, for test in xamarin test cloud without build from xcode? I currently try with the optool from command line, but not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* to link a prebuilt IPA with Calabash using Xamarin Test Recorder, however there are several limitations you should be aware of:

- **IPAs must be provided from the developer.** Apps from the app store are encrypted in a way that Test Recorder is unable to interact with.
- **Test Recorder requires a valid development provisioning profile and signing identity that can sign the app locally.** This is because when Test Recorder attempts to inject Calabash into the IPA it must be able to resign the app on the local system.
- **Test Recorder requires a iOS device you can deploy to based on the provisioning profile**. This is almost an addendum to my last point, but it distinct  because you will need a physical iOS device present for Test Recorder to record on; and it has to be included in the provisioning profile because that's an Apple requirement to install & run an app on a physical device.
- **Test Recorder is still in preview**. As such, bugs & issues may be more common compared to working with the rest of the Test Cloud toolchain. Fixes may also be slower in being pushed out compared to the rest of the tools. However, you can still report Test Recorder issues to the Test Cloud support team for investigation by going to https://testcloud.xamarin.com and clicking on the "Support" link at the top right hand side of the window.

Note: This answer is tweaked from the answer I wrote to a very similar question in the Xamarin Forums here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100461/do-i-need-the-source-code-to-execute-xamarin-test-recorder#latest

More info on  Xamarin Test Recorder: https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud/recorder